# Discretize an n-sphere?

Tags: spheres, projection

Suppose I have points uniformly randomly distributed throughout $R^n$, with coordinates restricted to some finite interval centered on the origin. It is then trivial to map those points into the discrete space $Z^n$, e.g. by applying the floor function to each coordinate. Given the assumption of uniformity, each point in the discrete space should then be associated with approximately the same number of source points in the original space.

Now, if we relax the initial assumption of uniformity, we can still achieve a uniform distribution of the number of source points mapped to any given discretized point by using a slightly more complex discretization procedure--rather than simply rounding down to the nearest integer, we can divide up each axis into discrete buckets of varying size, such that each range contains the same number of points whose coordinate values for that axis fall into that range.

Finally, assume that points are not distributed throughout $R^n$, but are in fact restricted to the surface of an (n-1)-sphere. What procedure could be used to map those points, whose distribution is not specified, to a discrete $Z^{n-1}$ space with a uniform distribution of how many source points are mapped to each discrete point?

Comment: It's somewhat unclear what your requirements are and what you're optimizing for. We're given a set $X$ of points on an $(n-1)$-sphere and are looking for a set $Y$ (of integer points in $\Bbb R^n$? How many?) and a mapping $f:X\to Y$ ...with what properties? That minimizes what?

Comment: Maybe: $f(x)$ is the closest element of $Y$ to $x$, and we want to minimize the variance of the set $\{|f^{-1}(y)|:y\in Y\}$?

Comment: @Karl. Arbitrarily many; I should be able to say "I want to divide this dimension into x buckets, and this dimension into y buckets, and this dimension into z buckets", and end up with a discrete space containing x*y*z points. And the differences between the number of X values that get mapped to the same Y value should be minimized.

Comment: @Karl The idea of an element of Y being close to x doesn't really make sense to me, as Y and X live in different spaces.

Comment: The way I formulated it, $X$ and $Y$ are both subsets of $\Bbb R^n$. You mention "a discrete $\Bbb Z^{n-1}$ space" - maybe it would help to clarify that. Or give an example of what the procedure you have in mind might output.

Comment: Oh I see, the number of buckets (in each dimension) is given.